# When is a general time-varying cost function $U(x, t)$ considered to be convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I found the following definition in a thesis but with no reference: A cost function $U(x, t)$ is said to be convex if it satisfies the following inequality:
$
U(\alpha x_1 + (1 - \alpha) x_2, t) \leq \alpha U(x_1, t) + (1 - \alpha) U(x_2, t)
$
for all $(x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n)$, $(0 \leq \alpha \leq 1)$, and $(t \in T)$, where $(T)$ is the time domain. In other words, for a general time-varying function $U(x, t)$, $U(x, t)$ is said to be convex if $U(x, t)$ is a convex function of $(x)$ for fixed $(t)$. Is it a valid definition? Can someone provide me with a valid **reference** where the convexity of a **time-varying** function is **defined** and discussed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Mathematically we don't distinguish between a "time varying function" of $n$ variables and a function with $n+1$ variables. Convexity of a function is defined using all of the arguments of the function - what you are looking for is something different.